# How to remove all access rules from folder AND all subfolders using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, access-control, subdirectory, removeall

I know this question was answered for a specific folder, but I would like to remove a user from all subfolders as well.

I tried to set the inheritance and propagation values to make sure the setting is inherited, but it still only applies for the root directory, no matter how I set the arguments. (part of) my code looks like this:

```
$inherit = "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$propagation = "None"
$Acl=get-acl $o2
$Accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($o1,"Read", $inherit, $propagation,"Allow")
$Acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($Accessrule)
Set-Acl -Path $o2 -AclObject $Acl
```

Comment: Do you want to leave the admins ACLs untouched? If you remove absolutely all the ACLs, only the owner of the top folder will be able to add ACLs, or you will need to take ownership.

Comment: Remove inheritable permissions on the top folder, then recurse into the subfolders and remove all non-inherited permissions.

Comment: well, turns out that the simplest solution so far is to add the following line to my code above:
ls $o2 -recurse | set-acl -aclObject $Acl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Careful with the following, it will remove ACLs**

**TEST BEFORE USING**

**I will strongly recommend making a ROBOCOPY with the full ACLs on a separate drive before using the following. If something is not right, you can always copy the files or the ACLs or both back.**

Ok here is something you can start with. Like Ansgar says, you pretty much loop through, the folder list, and for each folder you retrieve all Access Controls Entry (ACE) in each ACL.

If the ACE is not inherited, you remove it.

**Updated to use $o1**
Ok in this version the ACE needs to be assigned to the user defined by `$o1`.

I have not tested it, so make some tests and check the values step by step before unleashing hell.

```
$filepath = "<your drive letter>:"

$folders = @((get-item $filePath))
$folders += Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -ne $false }

Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{

    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder.FullName

    Foreach($access in $acl.access) 
    { 
        if ($access.isinherited -eq $false -and $access.IdentityReference.Value -eq $o1)
        { 
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($access) 
        }  
    } 
    Set-Acl -path $folder.fullname -aclObject $acl 
}
```

Comment: I do not want to remove ALL users, just a specific user ($o1 in my code).

Comment: I get your idea though. You gather all of the subfolders into a set of folders, and you remove the user from them one by one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that for a very large directory structure that you'll likely get much better performance with `Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse | where { $_.PSIsContainer -ne $false } | ForEach-Object {...}` since the pipe will start passing objects immediately instead of collecting them all into a variable first.  You'll need to process the root separately, however.  Also note that you'll need `Get-ChildItem -Force` to capture hidden and system files.